# Likelihood Ratio Test on Multiple Samples

Tags: likelihood

I have 32 samples and I can calculate the likelihood of each data point individually, but how would I calculate a total likelihood for the model (i.e. how well it fits all data points?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your samples independent and identically distributed, we have that the total likelihood can be computed as:

$f({x_{i}, .., x_{n} \| \theta}) = \prod_{i=1}^{n}f(x_{i}\|\theta)$

where f is the likelihood function, $\theta$ are your parameters and $x_{i}, .., x_{n}$ are your samples.

Comment: say I have 2 set of samples, set1 has one sample value = 0, set2 has two samples both = 0, both sets were generate by the same normal distribution which p(0) = 0.4, then set1's likelihood is 0.4 and set2's likelihood is 0.16? by sampling more I have a smaller likelihood? Is this formula right?